# Apache2 Web Server FIle/Folder Permissions

Tags: permissions, apache2

There seem to be as many different answers to this question as there are questions themselves! Setting up Apache2 (v2.4.41) and allowing it to create and use www-data isn't in itself the issue and that's what I have and need as some Web-based applications I am building need to be able to write to files. I had myself as the user but then it was impossible to open a file in the browser as writable and with www-data it is but I cannot save my programing in the desktop text editor.

However, how do I do this AND still be able to save files I'm working on in my desktop application along with being able to copy and move files and folders? I can't seem to find a way to do both.

Right now, ls -l shows this which lets me open writable files in a browser-based form:

```
drwxrwsr-x 15 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 26 12:14 html
```

but with this I cannot open files in the browser in a writable way:

```
drwxrwsr-x 15 don www-data 4096 Dec 26 12:14 html
```

. . . and with this, as above, I can edit and work on my files in my desktop editor but the Web server cannot write to them.

```
drwxrwsr-x 15 don don 4096 Dec 26 12:14 html
```

I have added myself to the www-data group but it seemed to make no difference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do a:

```bsh
chown don.www-data html
```

Or:

```bsh
chown www-data.users html
adduser don users
```

Comment: I realized that your code wasn't recursive so when I tried **sudo chown -R don.www-data /var/www/html** I can now save files in my desktop editor but they are no longer writeable from the site's programming. Using **chown www-data.users -R /var/www/html** the files are browser-writeable but I cannot do so using my desktop editor. I need to be able to do both and that's where I am having the problem!

Comment: I've been having to change ownership back and forth between editing and testing which is a real pain! Any ideas?

Comment: try also a chmod -R 775 /var/www/html and you need to add don to the users group! Here is a good explanation of linux file permissions. https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html

Comment: I was under the impression that folders were supposed to be 755 and I am already added to the www-data group.  However, I tried 775 and changed back to www-data.www-data while in the middle of copying over some files and immediately got permissions errors. I’ll check the link that was provided to see if it sheds any light but I believe it is one of many that I’ve already read.